# Split all of the files in a directory by 1000 lines and process them through a perl script

Tags: perl, for-loop, split, find

I used this line to try and split all of the files in a directory into smaller files and put them in a new directory.

```
cd /path/to/files/ && find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec split -l 1000 '{}' "path/to/files/1/prefix {}" \;
```

The result was 'no file found', so how do I make this work so that I split all of the files in a directory into smaller 1000-line files and place them in a new directory?

Later on...

I tried many variations and this is not working. I read another article that split cannot operate on multiple files. Do I need to make a shell script, or how do I do this?

I had a bright idea to use a loop. So, I researched the 'for' loop and the following worked:

```
for f in *.txt.*; do echo "Professing $f file..."; split -l 1000 $f 1split.ALLEMAILS.txt. ; done
```

*.txt.* is in all of the files in the working directory. the 'echo' command was optional. for the 'split' command, instead of naming one file, I replaced that with $f as defined by the 'for' line.

The only thing I would like to have been able to do is move all of these to another directory in the command.

Right now, I am stuck on the find command for moving all matching files. This is what I have done so far that is not working:

```
find . -type f -name '1split.*' -exec mv {} new/directory/{} \;
```

I get the error ' not a directory ' ; or I tried:

```
find . -type f -name '1split.*' -exec mv * . 1/ \;
```

and I get ' no such file or directory '

Any ideas?

I found that this command moved ALL of the files to the new directory instead of the ones specifically meeting the criteria '1split.*'

Answer (score 1):

So, the answers to my questions are:

```
for f in *.txt.*; do echo "Professing $f file..."; split -l 1000 $f 1split.ALLEMAILS.txt. ; done
```

and

```
mv *searchcriteria /new/directory/path/
```

I did not need a find command for this after all. So, combining both of these would have done the trick:

```
for f in *.txt.*; do echo "Professing $f file..."; split -l 1000 $f 1split.ALLEMAILS.txt. ; done
mv *searchcriteria /new/directory/path/ | echo "done."
```

---later on...

I found that this basically took 1 file and processed it.

I fixed that with a small shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

for f in /file/path/*searchcriteria ; ## this was 'split.*' in my case

  do echo "Processing $f in /file/path/..." ;

  perl script.pl --script=options $f > output.file ;

  done ;

echo "done."
```